# Integrate graphql into flask blueprint

Tags: python, flask, graphql, flask-sqlalchemy, graphene-python

I'm currently trying to integrate GraphQL (using graphene and flask_graphql) into my flask app. Tried a few tutorial from [here](https://medium.com/@fasterpancakes/graphql-server-up-and-running-with-50-lines-of-python-85e8ada9f637) and [here](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/sqlalchemy/en/latest/tutorial/). But seems none works in my situation.
Currently my project is like this

```
-manage.py
  |app
     |__init__.py (create_app is here)
     |mod_graphql (this is folder)
         |__init__.py (blueprint created here)
         |models.py
         |schema.py
         |controller.py
```

The issue is in both tutorial, it recommend to create Base and engine in the models file, I did the same, but I would need to read config file using current_app for the URI to create engine. But actually, because it happens in flask initialization, so there is no request context yet, so current_app doesn't exist. so everything fails. 
Would it be possible to help me setup this?

Below are some code:

```
app/__init__.py
create_app():
    ...
    from .mod_graphql import bp_graph
    app.register_blueprint(bp_graph)
    ...

mod_graphql/__init__.py

from flask import Blueprint
bp_graph = Blueprint('graphql', __name__)
from . import controller
from . import models
from . import schema

mod_graphql/models.py

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(current_app.config.get('BASE_URI'), 
             convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

class Model1_Model(Base):
...

class Model2_Model(Base):
...

mod_graphql/schema.py

class Model1(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1_Model
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)

class Model2(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2_Model
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()
schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, types=[Model1])


mod_graphql/controller.py

bp_graph.add_url_rule('/graphql',
                      view_func=GraphQLView.as_view('graphql',
                                                    schema=schema,
                                                    graphiql=True,
                                                    context={'session': 
                                                    db_session}))
@bp_graph.teardown_app_request()
def shutdown_session(exception=True):
    db_session.remove()
```

When I try to start server, it tells me:

Working outside of application context

Would you pls recommend the best practice to setup this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the flask initialization to define the DB connection. This way you can use Flask's internal implementation of connecting to the database without defining it on your own

*app/`__init__`.py*

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
```

Then all you need to do in your models is:

*app/models.py*

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Model1_Model(Base):
```

Then in your route definition instead of using the `db_seesion` from your model inside your context, you can reference Flask's `db` like `context={'session': db.session})` that you created in the `create_app()` function.

Comment: thanks mshaps. I'm using this exact same way to initialize the db. Inspired by your answer and found a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Try initiate the Blueprint in

```
    app.__init__
```

I got a same time like u,cos the

```
    __name__
```

should be app

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and couldn't figure out a way as well. I'm using the create_app() function in __init__.py to initialize all the component.

Comment: Nothing better than u get it

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to do it without using `current_app`:

1. in config.py, and multi database binding by:

   ```
   SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
   'db1': DB1_URI,
   'db2': DB2_URI
   }
   ```
2. in models.py, do this

   ```
   engine = db.get_engine(bind='db1')
   metaData = MetaData()
   metaData.reflect(engine)
   Base = automap_base(metadata=MetaData)

   class Model1(Base):
       __tablename__ = 'db1_tablename'
   ```

   In this way, the model will be able to access the proper database uri without `current_app`, but if `app_context` switches, potentially different solution will be needed